# PHP mail on windows server

Tags: php, sendmail

I have a problem with a form. Works fine on linux servers but not on windows ones. I' ve read that windows servers need some more parameters in the php file in order to be able to send the mail, tried some of them without any luck! So i am puzzled on what to do. This is the piece of code:

```
<?php
    $email_to =   'mail@mail.com'; 
    $name     =   $_POST['name'];  
    $email    =   $_POST['email'];
    $subject  =   "www.domain.com";
    $message  =   '<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2";><b>Name:</b> '.$_POST['name'].chr(10) . chr(10) . "<br><br>".
                  '<b>E-mail:</b> '.$_POST['email'].chr(10) . chr(10) ."<br><br>".
                  '<b>Subject:</b> '.$_POST['subject'].chr(10) . chr(10) ."<br><br>".
                  '<b>Message:</b> '.$_POST['message'];


    $headers  = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


    if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo 'sent';      
    }else{
        echo 'failed';   
    }

?>
```

FYI The website is hosted on whois.com.

Comment: You already read the answer... likely on Stack Overflow since this question is asked here multiple times per day.  PHP can use an SMTP server on Windows, which you configure in php.ini.  It's a PHP configuration, not your code.  Really though, give up on that and use something like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer so that you can use SMTP authentication and other helpful functionality (such as setting HTML e-mail up correctly).

Comment: @Brad, thanks for your reply.. i read about that just not so good with PHP.. anyway i read on whois.com in the FAQ section "All Whois.com Web Servers have SMTP Server installed and are capable of sending emails. You need to use localhost as the SMTP Server in your web forms or web applications, in order to send emails through the Web Server." Just puzzled on how impement that localhost on my code.

Comment: As I said, it has nothing to do with your code at all.  It's something you configure in php.ini.

Comment: ok thanks will give a try to PHPmailer

Comment: PHPmailer needs proper SMTP settings too. You will have the same problem. Define SMTP host, port and allow this port in firewall.